# How can I reset with send_break in this example of a boost::asio application?

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port, boost-asio

While creating an application with use of boost::asio, I adapted an example for my purposes.

However, after making it work, I am now trying to make it work better. In order to do so, I need to reset my serial-device somehow. In a similar application this is done through sending a `break` signal.

For some reason, I can't seem to do this without getting an exception.

I am using the `void send_break()` function, maybe this is the problem, because it seems that it will always throw an error.

This is the boost-code:

```
  /// Send a break sequence to the serial port.
  /**
   * This function causes a break sequence of platform-specific duration to be
   * sent out the serial port.
   *
   * @throws boost::system::system_error Thrown on failure.
   */
  void send_break()
  {
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    this->get_service().send_break(this->get_implementation(), ec);
    boost::asio::detail::throw_error(ec, "send_break");
  }

  /// Send a break sequence to the serial port.
  /**
   * This function causes a break sequence of platform-specific duration to be
   * sent out the serial port.
   *
   * @param ec Set to indicate what error occurred, if any.
   */
  boost::system::error_code send_break(boost::system::error_code& ec)
  {
    return this->get_service().send_break(this->get_implementation(), ec);
  }
```

This is the code I am trying to call the function from:

```
class minicom_client
{
public:
        minicom_client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, unsigned int baud, const string& device)
                : active_(true),
                  io_service_(io_service),
                  serialPort(io_service, device)
        {
                if (!serialPort.is_open())
                {
                        cerr << "Failed to open serial port\n";
                        return;
                }
                boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate baud_option(baud);             
                serialPort.set_option(baud_option); // set the baud rate after the port has been opened             
                serialPort.send_break();                
                read_start();
        }
```

*Edit:*

After playing with this for a while, I found that the error-code I am getting is `boost::asio::error::operation_not_supported;` - but how can this be, when this is a build in function?!

From *win_iocp_serial_port_service.hpp*:

```
  // Send a break sequence to the serial port.
  boost::system::error_code send_break(implementation_type&,
      boost::system::error_code& ec)
  {
    ec = boost::asio::error::operation_not_supported;
    return ec;
  }
```

Now I am really lost here.

Comment: yeah, this clears it pretty much - however, why it is implemented this way, I don't get it o_O have you any idea, how I can create a break singal, which is specified as *an RX input of non-idle state (0v) for more than 125ms*.

Comment: @llonesmiz - why did you delete your answer? you basically solved my problem, by pointing me to the some of the right sources. I had to use SetCommBreak|Sleep|ClearCommBreak and the right setup of my serial-port, now my device reset works - so THANKS! you'll get an accept, if you should undelete your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to open the COM port and send the break through the Windows API. The following code should work as long as you have included windows.h properly.

```
#include <windows.h>

TCHAR pcCommPort[512];
_tcscpy(pcCommPort, "COM1");   // Or COM2, COM3, ...

//  Open a handle to the specified com port.
handleToComPort = CreateFile(pcCommPort,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,      //  must be opened with exclusive-access
    NULL,   //  default security attributes
    OPEN_EXISTING, //  must use OPEN_EXISTING
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,      //  not overlapped I/O
    NULL); //  hTemplate must be NULL for comm devices

::SetCommBreak(handleToComPort);
::Sleep(125);           // Sleep 125ms to ensure a good break
::ClearCommBreak(handleToComPort);
::CloseHandle(handleToComPort); // Close the COM port only if you need to.
```